# Passing an array to a function with an odd format - "v+last+1"

Tags: c, arrays, function, argument-passing

In *The Practice Of Programming*, on the chapter regarding quicksort, there is some C code that walks through a basic algorithm for quicksort (I've compiled the code into a program that prints the arbitrary array values pre and post sorting):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void swap(int v[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}

void quicksort (int v[], int n)
{
    int i, last;
    if (n <= 1)
        return;
    swap(v, 0, rand() % n);
    last = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (v[i] < v[0]) 
        {
            swap (v, ++last, i);
        }
    }
    swap(v, 0, last);
    quicksort(v, last);
    quicksort(v+last+1, n-last-1);
}

void printIntegerArray(int arrayInput[], int arraySize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arrayInput[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[5] = {7, 10, 14, 12, 4};
    int arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    printf("Before sorting: ");
    printIntegerArray(array, arraySize);
    quicksort(array, arraySize); 

    printf("After sorting: ");
    printIntegerArray(array, arraySize);
}
```

I understand everything, except the second recursive call:

```
quicksort(v+last+1, n-last-1);
```

What does "v+last+1" do? I wouldn't assume C to change the size of an array at runtime, so is it simply saying that the input is 'an array, starting from V[last+1]' or is it something else? As always, sorry if I've missed this on another post. I've tried searching with a few variant versions of my question.

Comment: it is not for size changing, it is to say the next function call to start looking at the array from address `v+last`

Comment: Excellent book to be reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it simply saying that the input is 'an array, starting from V[last+1]' or is it something else?

It's pointer arithmetic, your guess is basically correct, except that it's really a pointer that's passed.

An array is always automatically converted to a pointer to the first element when passing as function argument. So when `v` is passed, it's really a pointer to its first element that is passed. While `v+last+1` is the pointer that points `last+1` elements after the first element of `v`.

Comment: I figured as such, thanks! Then in our initial method, when we pass the array (or any array for that matter), we're actually just passing array[0]. I noticed this same issue when I tried putting the arraySize expression inside of printIntegerArray. I figure the issue had to do something with getting the full size of the array (the first sizeof()) and guessed it had only passed the first indice into the function. Is that correct? I'm sorry if it's somewhat off-topic, but how would one then be able to pass the whole array in for use in the arraySize expression?

Comment: @RyanJamesSpencer When `array` is passed, it's actually converted to `&array[0]`. The function `quicksort` receives a pointer, it has no idea what the size is, so an additional parameter is used for this purpose. To pass the whole array is similar, the size must be passed explicitly, `arraySize` is the size of the array. And don't worry, it's NOT off-topic at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
quicksort(v+last+1, n-last-1);
```

is similar to

```
quicksort(&v[last+1], n-last-1);
```