# Python 'pointer arithmetic' - Quicksort

Tags: python, c, arrays, list, pointers

In idiomatic C fashion, one can implement quicksort in a simple way with two arguments:

`void quicksort(int inputArray[], int numelems);`

We can safely use two arguments for later subdivisions (i.e. the partitions, as they're commonly called) via pointer arithmetic:

```
//later on in our quicksort routine...
quicksort(inputArray+last+1, numelems-last-1);
```

In fact, I even asked about this before on SO because I was untrained in pointer arithmetic at the time: see [Passing an array to a function with an odd format - “v+last+1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141124/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-an-odd-format-vlast1)

Basically, **Is it possible to replicate the same behavior in python and if so, how?** I have noticed that lists can be subdivided with the colon inside of square brackets (the slicing operator), but the slice operator does not pass the list from that point on; that is to say that the 1st element (0th index) is still the same in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're aware, Python's slice syntax makes a copy, so in order to manipulate a subsection of a list (not "array", in Python) in place, you need to pass around both the list and the start-index and size (or end-index) of the portion under discussion, much as you could in C. The signature of the recursive function would be something like:

```
def quicksort( inputList, numElems, startIndex = 0 ):
```

And the recursive call would be something like:

```
quicksort( inputList, numElems-last-1, last+1 )
```

Throughout the function you'd add `startIndex` to whatever list accesses you would make.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for reminding me; I've reflected the update in my question (list to array). So, ultimately there is no way of implementing similar functionality with a dyadic argument list?

Comment: Dyadic argument list? Do you actually care about the arity of the function? I mean, you could define a class that contained a list plus the bounding information, and make the function call unary with one of those, or you could define a class that had C-array-style semantics, and work in that.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity and exploration. In fact, I shouldn't even be calling the C approach as 'functionality' because it is more clever than it is wise and certainly not always as legible to readers of the code (as with with my initial post about v+last+1). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you want to do something like that you could do the following:

```
# list we want to mutate
sort_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

#wrapper just so everything looks pretty, process could go here if we wanted
def wrapper(a, numlems):
    cut = len(a) - numlems
    # overwrites a part of the list with another one
    a[cut:] = process(a[cut:])

# processing of the slice
def process(a):
    # just to show it works
    a[1] = 15
    return a

wrapper(sort_list, 2)
print(sort_list)

wrapper(sort_list, 4)
print(sort_list)

wrapper(sort_list, 6)
print(sort_list)
```

This is probably considered pretty evil in python and I wouldn't really recommend it, but it does emulate the functionality you wanted.

---

For python you only really need:

```
def quicksort(inputList, startIndex):
```

Then creating and concatenating slices would work fine without the need for pointer like functionality.

Comment: You don't need to call `__setslice__` directly: `a[cut:] = process(a[cut:])`.

Comment: Oh very nice, I incorrectly assumed a slice always creates a copy, thanks for that.